# Minimum value of $(x + 2y)(y + 2z)(xz + 1)$ when $xyz=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima

> Let $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ be positive real numbers such that $xyz = 1.$ Find the minimum value of
>   $$(x + 2y)(y + 2z)(xz + 1).$$

---

I am pretty sure this problem either uses AM-GM or Rearrangement Inequality, but I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I solved your problem by another way. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the AM-GM inequality we have that :

$(x+2y)\geq 2 \sqrt{2xy}$

$(y+2z)\geq 2 \sqrt{2yz}$

$(xz+1)\geq 2 \sqrt{xz}$

Then $(x+2y) (y+2z) (xz+1) \geq 8 \sqrt{4 (xyz)^2}\implies (x+2y)(y+2z)(xz+1) \geq 16$

Comment: Well, you basically repeated what I just said :)

Comment: I  think we answered almost simultaneously, I didn't see that it already had an answer when I posted mine, when I started writing the solution there wasn't an answer

Comment: Oh, alright :), sorry

Comment: Note: Please show that equality can hold, otherwise you've only found a lower bound, and not necessarily the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

ALERT: this is my solution, not a hint.
$$\underbrace{(x+2y)}_{2AM \ge 2GM} \ \  \underbrace{(y+2z)}_{2AM \ge 2GM} \ \  \underbrace{(xz+1)}_{2AM \ge 2GM}\ge 2\sqrt {x \cdot2y} \cdot 2\sqrt {y \cdot2z} \cdot 2 \sqrt{xz} = 8 \sqrt{4x^2y^2z^2}=16xyz=16 $$